# Unable to properly import celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to run a Celery demo. It gives a import error.

```
     File "/home/anee/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/anee/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/anee/Documents/off-ds/t3/run_tasks.py", line 2, in <module>
    from t3tasks import longtime_add
  File "t3/t3tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
    from t3.celery import app
  File "t3/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

Here is my directory structure

```
t3 
    __init__.py
    celery.py
    run_tasks.py
    t3tasks.py
```

Celery file

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('t3',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['t3.t3tasks'])
```

Here is t3tasks.py file

```
from t3.celery import app
import time

@app.task
def longtime_add(x, y):
    print('long time task begins')
    # sleep 5 seconds
    time.sleep(5)
    print('long time task finished')
    return x + y
```

Here is run_tasks.py

```
from t3tasks import longtime_add
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = longtime_add.delay(1,2)
    print('Task result: ', result.result)
```

After starting celery

```
celery -A t3 worker --loglevel=info
```

I am running the tasks like this

```
python -m t3.run_tasks
```

Comment: this is not how to import celery task `from t3.celery import app`

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri I am following the demo from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1224515/Python-Celery-RabbitMQ-Tutorial). How can I properly import celery task?

Comment: ok, try this line in the idle does it work `from celery import Celery` if not then `pip install celery`

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri Still same error.

Comment: have you tried to `pip install celery` or whats the result of `pip show celery`

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri 1) I added from __future__ import absolute_import 2) I was running it from inside the t3 package. Came out of directory and ran  python -m t3.run_tasks, which worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file t3/celery.py to another name.

```
from celery import Celery
```

in your t3/celery.py tries to import Celery from t3/celery.py itself (instead of celery module in the library).